# asp.net mvc ajax.beginform file upload

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

is there a way i can file upload using ajax.beginform as i am using jquery dialog and can't use html.beginform

Basically i am implmenting a sort of wizard for initializing website on jquery dialog which need to have ajax there

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to use `Html.BeginForm()`? It just generates html for you - what you do to its output with jQuery is entirely up to you.

Comment: html.beginform invoke the parent page on submit from dialog

Answer (score 0):

There may be issues with that... if you are using JQuery, you may want to consider uploadify http://www.uploadify.com/ or other JavaScript implementations...

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Telerik file control](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload.aspx). It may help you.